# How do I run Windows 11 remotely without a physical monitor attached?

Tags: windows-11

I want to operate my Windows 11 machine remotely using Chrome Desktop to control and view it.
However, if I do not have a monitor / display attached, I am unable to set the resolution of the screen.

What would be a solution?
Do I need to simulate a monitor being attached?

Answer (score 3):

There exist dongles that act like a fake monitor.

Here is a random example that is cheap enough :
[HDMI Dummy Plug,Headless Ghost, Display Emulator （Fit Headless-1920x1080 New Generation@60Hz）](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XT1Z9TF):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just plug in video cable without monitor. Sounds silly but it works for some reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The gfx card usually senses what type of monitor is plugged in. It is possible that this workaround is for dumb monitors that dont respond to quering.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta are you saying that the smart gfx cards don;t work with all monitors? I would think they work with all monitors and monitor identity would be optional. Did you try my workaround btw?